# Asterisk to Asterisk connection via sip details

Tags: asterisk

I'm using Asterisk server as sip server.

When I use sip details on softphone or any sip client it work properly.

But when i try to connect other asterisk server to this sip server it failed to connect.

Comment: You should give us more information regarding your problem. Some steps that you have done so far to solve it, configuration of both asterisks, error logs. Otherwise you sound like make my job for me.

Comment: There are so many questions unanswered in here. what version of asterisk are you using? what is the error in log files? are they in the same subnet? etc. please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any info about exact issue in your qeustion.

Check this article

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Connect+2+servers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the iptables are disabled on another side. You may try to use IAX2 as it requires very less configuration on firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It is a question of how did you set up trunk to connect to another asterisk.

If you use same behaviour as your softphones - add `register` line to slave asterisk.

Or set up `friend` trunk to act without registration

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but I had to do something similar a few weeks ago.

**sip.conf (Group1)**

```
register=>group01:12345@10.0.2.2/group02
```

*You are group 1 and the IP Address of the Asterisk Server of the remote site is 10.0.2.2*

**In you extensions.conf (Group1)**

```
[group02]
exten => _2xxx,1,Answer()
exten => _2xxx,2,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@group02,60,r)
exten => _2xxx,3,Hangup()
```

Group 2 has to do the same thing vice versa

**sip.conf (Group2)**

`register=>group02:12345@10.0.1.2/group01`

**extensions.conf (Group2)**

```
[group01]
exten=>_1xxx,1,Answer()
exten=>_1xxx,2,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@group01,60,r)
exten=>_1xxx,3,Hangup()
```

Hope this helps